# Prevent click event after handling jQuery Mobile tap event on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile

To improve responsiveness in our web app on iPad, I switched from responding to the click event to responding to the jQuery Mobile "tap" event. It works great and is much more responsive, but it introduced a new error.

When users tap the screen on an iPad, iOS sends the TOUCHSTART and TOUCHEND events which jQuery Mobile treats as a "tap". But then 300ms later, iOS sends a "click" event. If I respond to the "tap" by advancing to the next page before the "click" occurs then the next page receives the "click" and if a button on the new page happens to appear in the location of the tap then it gets clicked.

My workaround for now is to give the user visual feedback in response to the "tap" but wait for the "click" before proceeding to the next page.

My question is whether it's possible to handle the "tap" and somehow tell Safari or iOS not to send the "click" at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can tell;

```
$('elementsSetThatCanBeTapped').on('tap', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();
   $(this).off('click');
})
```

Comment: It looks like e.preventDefault() is the winner.

e.stopPropogation() has no effect.

Comment: if it helps, I never write one without the other, preventDefault and stopPropagation, perhaphs is not ideal but is allways working

Comment: please whoever downvoted could add a reason why, because is the accepted answer and solved the problem

Comment: Don't do `off('click')` - if a device has both touchcreen and a mouse (like a touch laptop), you might confuse the users.

Comment: @riv how it can confuse the user?

Comment: @SyamsoulAzrien since `off('click')` completely removes the click handler, no mouse click will be recognized anymore once a tap has occured.

Answer (score 2):

A click event that's registered in the same location as a tap took place is known as a Ghost Click. jQuery Mobile have a partial solution in their vmouse Events.

But for a good roundup of your options you can't go past: http://www.appwards.nl/blog/2013/01/26/javascript-powered-webapps-and-click-versus-tap

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add a return false or `e.stopPropagation()` and attach same function to both tap and click that way only one of those events is fired.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to be able to use the web app on a computer without touch display, you might want to consider to use the click event together with the fastclick library: https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick This library eliminates the 300ms delay automatically.